# Native Base button missing styling

Tags: css, react-native, native-base

I have a `native-base` app and the styling works but seems to be partially missing from buttons. There are no errors and I have applied no custom styles in my app.

See the screenshot below. The buttons are missing their font color, padding, and maybe some other stuff. This is true for any button type (transparent, border, etc)

I am rendering the buttons with a simple

```
<Card onPress={console.log("hello") && this.props.navigation.navigate('Game')} key={game.location}>
  <CardItem header>
    <Left>
      <Icon name="ios-game-controller-a" />
      <Body>
        <Text>{game.location}</Text>
        <Text>Stations: {game.stationsCount}</Text>
      </Body>
    </Left>
    <Right>
      {this.gameStatus(game)}
    </Right>
  </CardItem>
  <CardItem>
    <Button primary block><Text>Join Game</Text></Button>
  </CardItem>
</Card>
```

Any idea why some styles would not be applied?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: It happened to me as well. I removed the "primary" attribute of the button and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `Button` came from `import { Button } from 'react-native'`, then you cannot style it. This component is for default style based on platform.

Here from official doc: (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html)

> If this button doesn't look right for your app, you can build your own button using TouchableOpacity or TouchableNativeFeedback. For inspiration, look at the source code for this button component. Or, take a look at the wide variety of button components built by the community.

You can have your own styled button by following this example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html

Comment: That's not the question though - sometimes native-base buttons don't render properly, it's an unrelated issue

Answer (score 6):

I have this problem all the time - make sure you're importing `<Text>` and `<View>` from native-base and not react-native.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Block button with Card]

You need to make use of `<Left>`, `<Body>` and `<Right>` when it comes to aligning components